# Has judgement day happened before also?

Tags: day-of-judgement

Holy Quran tells us that people according to their Believes and works will go to Heaven and Hell after the judgement day.

But Our Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said that he saw people burning in fire in hell during the journey in the night of destiny.

How is this possible that people were burnt in hell fire when the judgement day is yet to happen?

Comment: Could have been caused by time dilation since the Prophet did travel trillions of light years to the seven skies.

Comment: This may help: http://islamqa.info/en/89813

Answer (score 2):

Allah is the Creator of everything in the truest sense of the word.

We tend to assume that Allah only created the material things that we see, like the stars and the other celestial bodies, and everything between them, and also what lies within them.

However, Allah has also created other notions that we consider abstract, like time, and a sense of awareness of it within us. He has also created (written) qadr, or destiny, for each of His creation, and He can bend time as He pleases to make His Messenger (SAWS) see things that will happen in the "future," a notion that makes sense to us as humans.

Other than this, Allah can even bend space, so that we tend to see our earth and other bodies and the relation between them, insofar as their orbits are concerned. However, the reality of space may be vastly different from how we perceive it.

Ultimately, the entire universe that we see lies within our heads, since it is only our perception of it.

Comment: May Allah(SWT) guide Our perception